# How to load jquery full calender using ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, fullcalendar

I want to load full calender using Ajax. Data will pass from controller as json format. I dont know how to do it plz help.

My controller code:

```
public function calenderHoliday(){

    $appointments = Holiday::all();
    $items = Holiday::all();
    if(request()->ajax())
    {

        $data = Holiday::all();
        return response()->json( $data);
    }


    return view('admin.pages.calender_test',compact('appointments','items'));
}
```

My jquery Code

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
            $.ajax({
                url: config.routes.holiday_calender,
                type: "get",
                data: {
                    // our hypothetical feed requires UNIX timestamps
                    start: start.format(),
                    end: end.format()

                },
                success: function(doc) {
                    var events = [];
                    console.log(doc);
                    $(doc).find('event').each(function() {
                        events.push({
                            title: $(this).attr('title'),
                            start: $(this).attr('start') // will be parsed
                        });
                    });
                    callback(events);
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

My route:

```
Route::get('/test-calender', 'HolidayController@calenderHoliday')->name('calender.index');
```

The json
[image]

Plz help me... Calender shows up. But My data doesn't shows up.

Comment: You are treating the response (doc) as xml , not json. Show us what the json looks like

Comment: Edited my post and added pic

Comment: There is no `title` property or `start` property in that json either. Seems like you just copied some response code and have not adapted it to your own situation

Comment: Agreed you appear to have just copied the example from the documentation without understanding any of it it or considering whether it was actually relevant to your situation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FullCalendar will call this function whenever it needs new event data. This is triggered when the user clicks prev/next or switches views.

This function will be given **start** and **end** parameters, which are [Moments](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/utilities/Moment/) denoting the range the calendar needs events for.

**timezone** is a string/boolean describing the calendar's current timezone. It is the exact value of the [timezone](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/timezone/timezone/) option.

It will also be given callback, a function that must be called when the custom event function has generated its events. It is the event function's responsibility to make sure callback is being called with an array of [Event Objects.](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/Event_Object/)

Here is an example showing how to use an event function to fetch events from a hypothetical XML feed:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'myxmlfeed.php',
            dataType: 'xml',
            data: {
                // our hypothetical feed requires UNIX timestamps
                start: start.unix(),
                end: end.unix()
            },
            success: function(doc) {
                var events = [];
                $(doc).find('event').each(function() {
                    events.push({
                        title: $(this).attr('title'),
                        start: $(this).attr('start') // will be parsed
                    });
                });
                callback(events);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

[Source](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_function/)

I made some little changes:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: function(start, end, timezone, callback) {
        jQuery.ajax({
            url: 'schedule.php/load',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {
                start: start.format(),
                end: end.format()
            },
            success: function(doc) {
                var events = [];
                if(!!doc.result){
                    $.map( doc.result, function( r ) {
                        events.push({
                            id: r.id,
                            title: r.title,
                            start: r.date_start,
                            end: r.date_end
                        });
                    });
                }
                callback(events);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**Notes:** start and end MUST be ISO 8601. Another change was the use of format instead of unix (this made easier for me to deal with the code-behind)